# How to do LEFT JOIN a ON b = c, but if joined table is NULL, join on x instead in (Postgres) SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, sql-null

Given I have two SQL tables:

```
movies          
----------------
| id | title   |
----------------
| 1  | Matrix  |
| 2  | Titanic |
----------------


directors
-----------------------
| id | name | movieid |
-----------------------
| 1  | Steve | 1      |
-----------------------
```

If I do a typical left join;

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN directors ON directors.movieid = movies.id
```

Then then output will be similar to:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | title   | id   | name  | movieid |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | Matrix  | 1    | Steve | 1       |
| 2  | Titanic | NULL | NULL  | NULL    |
-----------------------------------------
```

Because for movie `2` there is no `director`, as expected.

However, in the cases where the join results in a `NULL` match, I want to provide a default value:

In pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN directors ON directors.movieid = (movies.id || 1)
```

Meaning, if the join results in a `NULL` match, join on the (default) value `1` instead, which would return ideally for me:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | title   | id   | name  | movieid |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | Matrix  | 1    | Steve | 1       |
| 2  | Titanic | 1    | Steve | 1       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Meaning, I want to provide a default director for all movies, if the JOIN fails.

Is it possible to do something like this in (Postgres) SQL?

Comment: Your question is not clear, better update with more details. Not sure why below answers solved the problem but get down vote.

Comment: What do "the join results in a NULL match" & "on the (default) value 1" mean? (Your example does not have the ON evaluating to NULL for any row.) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. 
[mre] PS Giving non-code that you don't explain does not explain. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to work with additional joins and operations, you need to create a CTE for directors of each movie and then use that CTE table instead of the directors table.

```
WITH cte
AS (
 SELECT COALESCE(directors.id, d2.id) AS id
  ,COALESCE(directors.name, d2.name) AS name
  ,COALESCE(movies.id, d2.movieid) AS movieid
 FROM movies
 LEFT JOIN directors ON directors.movieid = movies.id
 LEFT JOIN directors d2 ON d2.movieid = 1
 )
SELECT *
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN cte ON cte.movieid = movies.id
```

Output with additional data:

| id | title | id | name | movieid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Matrix | 1 | Steve | 1 |
| 2 | Titanic | 1 | Steve | 2 |
| 3 | Avatar | 2 | Mark | 3 |
| 4 | Mission Impossible | 1 | Steve | 4 |

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=df73f765ce2b8fbc30b6778c485091ad).

In case in `movieid` field you require it to match with directors' table, add another field in cte  `,COALESCE(directors.movieid, d2.movieid) AS dmovieid` and use that in `SELECT` statement (but don't use it in the join). E.g. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b82bd1f00dcd9c4a64eb5c8895c073bf)

Comment: This is just a copy of my answer unless using cte which is a well known concept people doing SQL should know by default.

Comment: @JonasMetzler: How is it just a copy of your answer? You have not given the solution which the OP is asking which I have given here.

Comment: AS I said, I gave the identic query you used in your CTE and of course, my answer IS correct which can be verified on the fiddle I provided. If my answer was not correct, yours isn't it, too, because you just use my query within a cte.

Comment: @JonasMetzler: First, I didn't copy your answer, I just wrote the query how it should be written. Second, after OP's comments on your answer, I wrote what OP was asking. But it seems like the OP is confused itself. Also you should downvote if the answer is incorrect or blatant copy. I have provided a different solution than yours.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the OP is very unclear and don't appreciate the efforts and quite correct answers here. But even after the comments of him, he told he would like to provide a default value for the JOIN and this is done in the case when construct of my anwer. Your cte doesn't change the logic of my query, so it's no difficult except you can use it as "one join" instead of two.

Comment: But sorry if you wrote this query on your own and "independant" of my answer. Then this was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two `JOIN`, one joining existing entries and one joining the others with the movieid as 1 and then use `COALESCE` to replace NULL values by the values of your "fallback":

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, 
COALESCE(d.id, d2.id) AS directorId, 
COALESCE(d.name, d2.name) AS name,
COALESCE(d.movieid, d2.movieid) AS movieId
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN directors d ON d.movieid = m.id
LEFT JOIN directors d2 ON d2.movieid = 1;
```

**UPDATE** since the OP added further information:
In order to prevint a second `JOIN`, you can use a `CASE WHEN` construct instead. Here the first option, just using fix default values:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, 
CASE WHEN d.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE d.id END AS directorId, 
CASE WHEN d.name IS NULL THEN 'Steve' ELSE d.name END AS name,
CASE WHEN d.movieid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE d.movieid END AS movieid
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN directors d ON d.movieid = m.id;
```

If you even want to select the default values instead of providing fix values, you can use sub queries within the `CASE WHEN` part:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, 
CASE WHEN d.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE d.id END AS directorId, 
CASE WHEN d.name IS NULL THEN (SELECT name FROM directors WHERE id = 1) 
ELSE d.name END AS name,
CASE WHEN d.movieid IS NULL THEN (SELECT movieid FROM directors WHERE id = 1)  
ELSE d.movieid END AS movieid
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN directors d ON d.movieid = m.id;
```

Use `DISTINCT` or `LIMIT 1` or similiar within the sub queries if necessary, this depends on your setup.
Please see working fiddle here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f40ef8512f146924c58b8bb64d04dedf)

Comment: This should work, if you only want movies and directors, unfortunately, I have additional LEFT JOINS and other operations to do after this.

Comment: @corgrath: I updated the answer. If this still doesn't help you, please ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: > Sorry, I don't understand your problem. This answer solves the issue you descibed, 

 ---- No, my question was about how to basically perform a default LEFT JOIN, if the ordinary one fails. The answer you suggested was how to manipulate the final result set. That's two different things.

Comment: No, I asked my question very explicitly. I literally wrote "Meaning, if the join results in a NULL match, join on the (default) value 1 instead,". I literally wrote I wanted a default JOIN, not to manipulate the final result set.

Comment: Your "CASE" is an update of your original answer. My comment was regarding your first original answer, the only one you had provided then.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH m AS(
SELECT movies.id, movies.tittle
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN directors
ON movies.id = directors.movieiD
WHERE directors.movieiD IS NULL
), 
d AS (
SELECT * FROM directors WHERE directors.id = 1
)

SELECT m.*, d.* FROM m, d

UNION

SELECT movies.id, movies.tittle, directors.id, directors.name, directors.movieid 
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN directors
ON movies.id = directors.movieiD
WHERE directors.movieiD IS NOT NULL
```

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3b90b49d07a6c50c2638d2c0fc66d72c